# Decomposition of oxalic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

Normally, carboxylic acids on heating form an anhydride. **However**, Oxalic acid on heating undergoes decomposition to yield $\ce{(CO + H2O)}$.

**Why** does not Oxalic acid form an anhydride?

Comment: Have a look at the hypothetical molecular structure of [oxalic anhydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalic_anhydride). How stable do you think it is?

Comment: "Normally, carboxylic acids on heating form an anhydride." Who said that? Never trust textbooks that give chemical "facts" without presenting the evidence.

Comment: Btw. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxane_tetraketone

Comment: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/1998/p1/a803430c

Comment: Furthermore, oxalic acid produces $\ce{H_2O + CO + CO_2}$ on heating

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say oxalic acid does not form self condensing anhydride for certain because there is a publication in a higher rank journal calming they have synthesized ethanedioic anhydride dimeric compound $\bf{1}$ (Ref.1). Until someone proves they were mistaken, that fact stays. The even more unusual anhydride, ethanedioic (oxalic) anhydride momomer was not isolated, but believed to be the intermediate during the decomposition of $\bf{1}$ to $\ce{CO + CO2}$. Yet, it still has a CAS number: CAS 308818-63-5, probably gotten from this sited publication (Ref.1), abstract of which states that:

> Ethanedioic (oxalic) acid anhydride $\bf{1}$ was prepared for the first time and its dimeric cyclic nature established by spectroscopic and chemical evidence. The strong instability of 2-chloro-2-oxoethanoic acid $\bf{3}$ was incidentally observed. The chemical behaviour of $\bf{1}$ with $\ce{MeOH}$ and $\ce{CH2N2}$ was investigated.

[image: Ethanedioic (oxalic) acid anhydrides]

The compound $\bf{3}$ mentioned in the abstract is oxalic acid monochloride ($\ce{HO2C-COCl}$). According to the authors, unsuccessful attempts have been made as early as 1908 (Ref.2) when Staudinger has evidently dealt with likely intermediate $\bf{2}$  in the decomposition process.

During the present study, $\bf{1}$ was achieved by adding  ethanedioyl dichloride ($\ce{ClOC-COCl}$) to silver salt of oxalic acid ($\ce{AgO2C-CO2Ag}$) at $\pu{-15 ^\circ C}$. The evidence for formation of $\bf{1}$ was the sharp single peak at $\pu{144.94 ppm}$ in $\ce{^{13}C}$-NMR spectrum run at $\pu{-15 ^\circ C}$ (Ref.1). The calculated value of $\ce{^{13}C}$-NMR signal for $\bf{1}$ is $\pu{154 ppm}$. Also, the authors noted $\bf{1}$ is indifinitely stable at $\pu{-30 ^\circ C}$ (Ref.1).

**References:**

1. Paolo Strazzolini, Alberto Gambi, Angelo G. Giumanini, Hrvoj Vancik, "The reaction between ethanedioyl (oxalyl) dihalides and $\ce{Ag2C2O4}$: a route to Staudinger’s elusive ethanedioic (oxalic) acid anhydride," *J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. 1* **1998**, 2553-2558 (DOI: 10.1039/A803430C).
2. H. Staudinger, "Oxalylchlorid," *Chem. Ber.* **1908**, *41*, 3558-3567.

Comment: The story has progressed with Professor Rzepa's recent blog post https://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=25270 suggesting that the compound is more stable than experiment suggests.  It's instability may be due to acid contamination.